# PHP: Pre-fill a PDF file' fields and save them as default

Tags: php, pdf

I created a PDF file with some fields. I need users to fill out a HTML form and use these data to populate the fields in this file.

Right now, users have the link to that PDF file. They fill out the form, but they can't save it nor email it. I need the file to keep the values users type (perhaps save those values as the file' default) and allow them to save that copy in their devices, to latter email the file.

I was reading that PHP-PDF is limited and that there's other solutions out there. I am not sure if the default PHP-PDF functions are enough or if I'll need to look for an external PDF solution?

Answer (score 0):

This appears like a simple server-side form filling task.

An industrial-strength solution would be using FDFMerge by Appligent, where you could, for example have already a PDF for gathering the primary information, submit as FDF, and feed this FDF into the "big" Template PDF. Or, if you have to add more data server-side, you might also submit as HTML POST, create the FDF on the fly (pretty easy, because FDF is a structured text format), and feed that into FDFMerge.

If you prefer developing a server-side solution using PDF creating/modifying libraries, you dan do so, using iText, or pdflib or others allowing server-side filling.

It essentially comes to which way would be the most cost and time efficient way to solve the problem.